# Is there a way to group/collate LINQ queries e.g. multiple .Include calls?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Is there a way to "group up" the `.Include` calls below & encapsulate them in another method, which I can call like below?

```
var entity = _db.Entity.AsNoTracking()
            .AsSplitQuery()
            .Include(x => x.Prop1)
            .Include(x => x.Prop2)
            .Include(x => x.Prop3)
            .Include(x => x.Prop4)
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
```

Something like:

```
 var entity = _db.Entity.AsNoTracking()
            .AllIncludes()
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
```

I know about extension methods on IEnumerable but I couldn't find what I need.

Comment: `public static IQueryable<Entity> AllIncludes(this IQueryable<Entity> source) { return source.Include(x => x.Prop1); }` perhaps?

Comment: This is definitely possible, you need an extension method off `DbSet<Entity>` or `IQueryable<Entity>` (or both) so that at compile time, the code can discern the properties available to include

Comment: I would recommend you don't do this.   You will end up with IncludeAll in every query, even when it's not necessary.    It sounds like you think you need it, but you shouldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by writing an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods), which will allow you to "add" an `AllIncludes` method on top of the database entity.

This will allow you to encapsulate the `.Include` calls.

Assuming `_db.Entity` is of type `IQueryable<Entity>`:

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
    {
        public static IQueryable<Entity> AllIncludes(this IQueryable<Entity> source)
        {
            return source
                .Include(x => x.Prop1)
                .Include(x => x.Prop2)
                .Include(x => x.Prop3)
                .Include(x => x.Prop4);
        }
    }
```

Call, as expected:

```
 var entity = _db.Entity.AsNoTracking()
            .AllIncludes()
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
```